# How can I increase brightness on my macbook above the limit?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I recently purchased the new macbook and when comparing it to my 2013 macbook retina, the newer model is much dimmer, it was as if I downgraded. Is there any way to "hack" the brightness in the backend to make it brighter than what the settings are?

Comment: I wish I could do the same. My 2018 MacBook Pro is still too dim when used outside at max brightness.

Answer (score 1):

According to reviews screen should have the following brightness levels:

- [MacBook 12" 2017](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Apple-MacBook-12-2017-Laptop-Review.230656.0.html#toc-display): about **350 cd/m^2**
- [MacBook Pro Retina 13" Late 2013](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Apple-MacBook-Pro-Retina-13-Late-2013-Notebook.105035.0.html#toc-display): **330 cd/m^2**

So the MacBook 12" should be at least equally bright as your MacBook Pro Retina 13".

You cannot increase the screen's brightness above 100 %. Please contact Apple or your vendor to exchange your MacBook or to repair it.